# Not extracting /home/robert/tesstutorial/aratuned_from_ara/ara.lstm, since this component is not present

Tags: ocr, tesseract, lstm

I'm trying to train the Tesseract4.0 following the steps in the tutorial:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00---Replacing-Top-Layer-Example

But when I execute the command:

> mkdir -p ~/tesstutorial/nor_layer
>
> $ combine_tessdata -e ../tessdata/nor.traineddata ~/tesstutorial/nor_layer/nor.lstm

An error message is given by the system, which is shown as following: Not extracting /home/robert/tesstutorial/nor_layer/nor.lstm, since this component is not present.

Why do I receive this error? The message in the tutorial shows: "Wrote /home/shree/tesstutorial/nor_layer/nor.lstm"  represents nor.lstm will be written.
But why the system hint the nor.lstm file not present? Can you help me... (Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are most probably using tessdata from version 3. You have to use tessdata from the `tessdata_best` repository on Github.